# Different between $.each and ko.utils.arrayForEach

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to understand the difference between $.each and ko.utils.arrayForEach, there is something more that a array iterations ?

I am using ko.utils.arrayForEach because I am working with knockout js but I just have curiosity.

Comment: Did you read the respective documentation?

Comment: To be fair, it's not really clear what the difference between the two are in the Knockoutjs documentation. I did find this, which is a post given by someone who is a KO expert. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knockoutjs/Ep85EFQLSPs/0FpB2ubftvYJ    So it looks like there isn't much of a difference.

Comment: Neither does this page really state what the difference is: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ko.utils.arrayForEach` doesn't depend on jQuery and is simply a shortcut to writing something like:

```
for (var i = 0, j = myArray.length; i < j; i++) {
    someMethod(myArray[i]);
}
```

It only works with arrays.  jQuery is not a strict dependency of Knockout.  If it is available, then there are a couple of places where Knockout will use it (string to DOM parsing and event handling).

`$.each` requires jQuery (obviously) and is intended to be way more flexible.  It can iterate over properties in an object as well as arrays and work with jQuery objects.  It also gives you an index while you are looping.